# x is an element in (-1/n, 1/n). What is the intersection of the sets for all natural numbers n?

Tags: real-analysis

$x$ is an element in $(-1/n, 1/n)$. What is the intersection of the sets $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$?

I'm debating if it is $0$ or an empty set.

Comment: It's not clear what "taking $n\rightarrow\infty$" means. Do you mean to intersect all of these sets?

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant. I assumed the intersection of the sets (-1/n, 1/n) where n ∈ N would be the same as taking n -> inf. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

The only real number that belongs to $(-1/n,1/n)$ for every integral $n$ is zero. This is a consequence of the completeness of $\mathbb R$. But your question in somehow unclear.

Comment: I don't think the question is unclear. It's asking about the limit of a sequence of sets. As far as I know, there are at least two definitions of the limit of a sequence of sets (the [set-theoretic limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_limit), and the one given by the [Hausdorff metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance)), but both of them give the same answer in this case: it's the set $\{0\}$.

Comment: I thought since -1  and 1 can't be elements of (-1, 1), then so 0 can't be an element of (0, 0)?

Comment: The number 0 is not an element of $(0,0)$, but $(0,0)$ doesn't appear in this intersection.  There's no $n\in\mathbf{N}$ so that $(-1/n,1/n)=(0,0)$.

Comment: @LinsuHan: Note that only *finite* intersections of open sets (of which open intervals are a special case) are guaranteed to be open. In your case, you've got a sequence of shrinking sets, therefore the limit is equal to the intersection. But as the sequence is infinite, so is the number of intersected sets, and thus it is perfectly allowed that the intersection is not open; and indeed that is what happens here. The intersection is $\{0\}$ which is not open (and in particular not an open interval).